# Issues with reference video framerate

Tags: animation

I have some reference videos taken at 120 fps, my project is 30 fps. Do I just have to animate at 120 fps and then scale back down to 30?

Comment: What about scaling the videos to 30 fps first?

Comment: That depends on what you are trying to do. Are you rendering the animation to mix the video elsewhere? Using blenders VSE to mix the two? Will the final video be 120 or 30fps?